# TB 78 genreated key cannot be import into gpg

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg

I generated a ECC key then save the private key to file. Then I can import the key to tb78. However, when I try to import it to gpg2, it failed:

```
gpg: key E66BE8B832B7CE7A: "a@example.com" not changed
gpg: key E66BE8B832B7CE7A/B9E46E7832EBF7FA: error sending to agent: Bad secret key
gpg: error reading 'a@example.com-(0xE66BE8B832B7CE7A)-secret.asc': Bad secret key
gpg: import from 'a@example.com-(0xE66BE8B832B7CE7A)-secret.asc' failed: Bad secret key

sec   ed25519/E66BE8B832B7CE7A 2021-03-10 [SC]
      654FBB6321B58F094B30BBD6E66BE8B832B7CE7A
uid                 [ unknown] a@example.com
ssb#  cv25519/B9E46E7832EBF7FA 2021-03-10 [E]
```

If you generate RSA keys, the exported file can be imported without problem.

anyone know why? is this a bug from tb78 or is there some option I need to turn on when I import/export?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.gnupg.org/T5114 so it is actually a bug in gpg.